# Can't Input Japanese Text in Steam Game Using Apple Developer Game Porting Toolkit

Tags: language, gaming, wine, steam, macos-sonoma

I'm running Whiskey Version 1.1.0 (17), os Sonoma Version 14.0 Beta (23A5312d), Steam is up to date, Game Porting Toolkit 1 Beta 3. I'm trying to run a Japanese game, Winning Post 10 2023 that requires typing to begin the game (player name, horse names, etc). In the past when this happened, I'd do the following:

On Steam click on the game in `My library` -> `Manage (settings)` -> `General` -> `Launch Options` -> `LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 %command%`.

However, when I do this now, it says:

> "command not found"

How can I enable Japanese locale within Whisky to be able to type full-width Japanese characters within games?

Comment: If this is for Mac, why is there Windows 10 in tags? You don't need to describe the app in your question regardless.

Comment: Because Whisky is running Windows 10 via my Mac OS Sonoma